# CSS sticky table header with scrolling and position absolute

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I'm trying to create a table with sticky headers (without using `position: sticky`. The table also has overflow scrollbars, but this causes multiple issues with the CSS I have right now. I have a working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-1ge8v (html and css are defined in `App.vue`).

The issues I have with the current CSS are:

1. Scrolling horizontally, the border-bottom of the header row stops mid-way.
2. Scrolling horizontally, `Heading` is not sticky (it should always stay at the same position. (See 3.)
3. Scrolling horizontally and vertically, the column headers aren't scrolled with the current viewport. The `Heading` stays sticky though, which is correct behavior.

I've tried multiple variants of `overflow`, `position`ing and the like, but couldn't figure out what's wrong with my current CSS.

Comment: You should add the vue tag

Comment: Well, it's not really a vue question though... I only use vue for the `scrollAtTop` flag and generating content.

Comment: If I don't know vue, I'm a little lost on your link. It was just to help

Comment: For the border-bottom issue of the header, maybe try to stylize the border-bottom of div sticky-above

Answer (score 0):

First issue is happening because there is visibility hidden in line number 31 App.vue file.

Comment: If you remove visibility property from line number 25 and 31. Both of your problem will be solved.